# Restriction to single particle subspace

Tags: quantum-mechanics

In Anastopoulos and Hu - *A Master Equation for Gravitational Decoherence: Probing the Textures of Spacetime* (https://arxiv.org/abs/1305.5231), they restrict the system to a single particle subspace (p. 14, sec 3.4). I have been trying to reproduce the result of the paper but I don't understand how they do this.

The starting equation is a master equation of the form:

$$
\frac{d \rho_t}{dt} = - i [H_0 + \frac{\kappa}{2} V_g, \rho_t] + [H_I, \rho_t]
$$
Where $\rho_t$ is the density matrix for the matter system, $H_0$ is the free Hamiltonian, $V_g$ is the potential term due to the matter fields and I summed all the interaction terms between the matter and gravity fields as $H_I$.

To project this equation on the single particle subspace, they substitute the density matrix of the shape:
$$ 
\rho = \int \frac{d^3p}{(2 \pi)^3} \int \frac{d^3 p'}{(2 \pi)^3} <p| \rho_1 |p'> a_p^\dagger |0> <0| a_{p'}
$$
where a and $a^\dagger$ are annihilation and creation ladder operators for the quantized matter fields. And $\rho_1$ is the single particle density matrix. 
They then "retain only terms which preserve this form".

I think I understand why they do this, they basically put a projection operator inside the density matrix right?

I also think I understand how they take the commutator with the free Hamiltonian part. I think this works something like this:
$$
[H_0, \rho_t] 
= \int \frac{d^3p}{(2 \pi)^3} \int \frac{d^3 p'}{(2 \pi)^3} \left( H_0 <p| \rho_1 |p'> |p> <p'| - <p| \rho_1 |p'> |p> <p'| H_0 \right) \\
= \int \frac{d^3p}{(2 \pi)^3} \int \frac{d^3 p'}{(2 \pi)^3} \left( <p| \rho_1 |p'> \omega_p |p> <p'| - <p| \rho_1 |p'> |p> <p'| \omega_{p'} \right) \\
= \int \frac{d^3p}{(2 \pi)^3} \left( <p| \rho_1 |p'> \omega_p \delta_{pp'} - <p| \rho_1 |p'> \delta_{pp'} \omega_{p'} \right) \\
= [ \omega_p , \rho_1] = [\sqrt{p^2+m^2}, \rho_1]
$$

**Problem:**
I am really struggling with figuring out how the perform the one particle subspace restriction for the term $V_g$ (which is composed of many creation/annihilation ladder operators) since you can't use the operator $H_0$ there.

I hope someone can give me some tips in the right directions! If there are any books or articles on this subject please let me know too.